# Loading raw VBO data via MappedByteBuffer into OpenGL (not working)

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo, bytebuffer, filechannel

I've attempted to load raw, uncompressed VBO data via the method presented in a talk Google did at GDC 2011. This method uses a MappedByteBuffer to quickly load the data in a subsequent call to glBufferData. Unfortunately, for me, it's just not working. I was able to find a hacky work around for it (its commented out in my code below), but I would like to get this working without that hack. Here is a sample of my code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(location));
FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

// Hackery because passing mbb to glBufferData isn't working. 
//FloatBuffer fb = mbb.asFloatBuffer();
//float triangles[] = new float[fb.capacity()];
//for(int i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
//    triangles[i] = fb.get(i);
//}
//fb = FloatBuffer.wrap(triangles);

bufferInfo = new int[3];
bufferInfo[0] = newBufferID();
int size = (int)fc.size();

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, mbb, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: having the same problem. I don't think the example code actually works on all devices / implementations.

Comment: Yeah, at this point, I agree with that. FWIW, my "hack" is still faster than using an InputStream. This section of code is executed many times for some fairly sizable mesh data, and it is not causing any visible slow-downs.

Answer (score 1):

Two years passed since your post, but this is the only entry on Stack Overflow regarding MappedByteBuffer and loading data to VBO and I think I found the solution.

In my opinion problem is not with this code, but with the data you're trying to load. In my case it helped when I've changed endianness of stored vertex data to little endian.

This is just like Google does it in provided example: point are generated using sphere.c, so if I run their program I get values in little endian and that's why their demo works. When I tried to store values from Java using DataOutputStream I got big endian order.

Comment: Need to try this out... Never found a solution to the original problem. Maybe this is it!

Comment: Holy smokes, hours of my life gone, because of a similar problem with the endianness of `ByteBuffer` written to with floats via `ByteBuffer#asFloatBuffer` != the endianness of a `FloatBuffer` when each is passed to `glBufferData`. What a terrible feeling.